# Python console works - but file isn't for Pi-3 camera

Tags: python

I'm using a copy of very simple Pi-3 camera Python app.

```
import picamera
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.capture('test.jpg')
```

If I run those lines in Python 3 (IDLE) console, it works.

If I save the same 3 lines of code in a file and run it, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has not attribute 'PiCamera'
```

[image]

Comment: It could be that you're implicitly calling Python 2.x when you should be calling Python 3.x or vice versa. What's the exact command you use to call the script containing the 3 lines? Try typing `python your_script.py` and `python3 your_script.py` and see if there's a difference.

Comment: I'm using the Python 3 IDLE.  I can run/file in that IDE, or run in console $ python3 picamera.py - and get the same error.

Comment: python or python2 gives me the same error.

Comment: Ok, odd. You can write a script containing only these two lines: `import picamera` and `dir(picamera)`. The `dir()` command will show you all the methods and attributes of the module in question. What do you see when you run that in python2.x and python 3.x? Anything resembling "PiCamera"?

Comment: Yes - >>> import picamera
>>> dir(picamera)
['Blue', 'CircularIO', 'Color', 'Green', 'Hue', 'Lightness', 'PiCamera', 'PiCameraAlreadyRecording', 'PiCameraCircularIO', 'PiCameraClosed', 'PiCameraError', 'PiCameraMMALError', 'PiCameraNotRecording', 'PiCameraRuntimeError', ...

Comment: Those `>>>` look like interpreter or IDLE output. If it's already working in IDLE but not in a separate script, you need to put the lines in a script and run it to see what's going on. I forgot to add the `print` statement in my last comment. The script contents should be these two lines: `import picamera` and `print(dir(picamera))`.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I found the problem.  I named one of my python apps picamera.py and it was getting imported instead of the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP was getting an `AttributeError` rather than an `ImportError`, *something* was clearly being imported correctly but simply didn't have the method `PiCamera()`.

By calling `dir(picamera)` from a script, not in IDLE, to get a list of all available module methods, we found out that he was actually importing a different, home-made script with the same name as the `picamera` module (`picamera.py`). It probably worked in IDLE because it runs from a different folder.

So... Use `dir()` when you get an `AttributeError` and avoid using module names for your home-made scripts - it'll make things less confusing.